# how to configure spring cloud streams to poll multiple records at once

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'd like to write consumer which poll at once multiple records.
Mechanism should work like this:

1. Poll 50 records as list
2. Do something
3. If any of records would not be commited, once again process all of 50 records.
   My current config:

```
    spring:
      cloud.stream:
        kafka.streams.binder.brokers: ${bootstrap-server}
        default.content-type: application/json
        function.definition: functionName
        bindings:
          functionName-in-0.destination: test_topic,test_topic1,test_topic2
    
        kafka.streams.binder:
          configuration:
            processing.guarantee: exactly_once
            application.server: ${bootstrap-server}
            commit.interval.ms: 1000
          stateStoreRetry.maxAttempts: 5
          functions:
            functionName.applicationId: functionName
```

At this moment I receive one message in this function:

```
    @Bean
    public Consumer<KStream<String, String>> functionName() {
        return message -> message.transform((k,v) -> doSomething(k,v));
    }
```

Any helpful answer to my questions or to my code/configuration will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported by Kafka Streams; you can do it using the message channel binder by setting `batch-mode` to true.